# How to access $dirty, $dirty value of bootstrap-ui datepicker?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

How to access $valid, $dirty value of [bootstrap-ui datepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker)?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
    <pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>
    <pre>Valid is: <em>|{{dt.$valid}}|</em></pre>
    <pre>Dirty is is: <em>|{{dt.$valid}}|</em></pre>
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min="minDate" max="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" />
        <button class="btn" ng-click="open()"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
    </div>

    <hr />
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[planker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eQPxNetSVITfCW53Q1G7?p=preview)

Comment: figured it out ( form.dt.$valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to wrap your inputs with a `<form>` or `ng-form` (the same as far as Angular is concerned), preferably at the same level with the controller (or at least wrapping the controller as well) and give a name both to the form and the input:

```
<div ng-form="theForm" ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
    <input ... name="theInput" />
    <span>{{ theForm.theInput.$valid }}</span><!-- this works now -->
</div>
```

I prefer having my controller in the same element or below the (ng-)Form because then code in the controller can also access the form and perform additional operations based on the validity, dirty etc flags. Access the form as `$scope.formName` and the named inputs as `$scope.formName.inputName`.

Forked plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/nHRuDgoktX9xclex4DDH?p=preview